# Add the [main] link back into the new mSO top bar!

Tags: script

[image]

### About

Why did you create it? Because I was annoyed at the lack of a main link. Who is it for? People that want the link back. How does it work? With JavaScript magic. What problem does it solve? It puts the link back.

### Available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Undo1/SE-Topbar-MainMeta)!

---

#### Platform

Anything that can run JS userscripts.

### Contact

I created it, ping me here or at GitHub.

Comment: fork adding back the name too: https://github.com/Gabro/SE-Topbar-MainMeta